# How to obtain the board name of a given Android Smartphone

Tags: android, android-source

I'm building LineageOS from source and want to find out this simple thing. According to the [AOSP documentation](https://source.android.com/source/add-device):

> The device/board layer represents the physical layer of plastic on the device (i.e. the industrial design of the device). For example, North American devices probably include QWERTY keyboards whereas devices sold in France probably include AZERTY keyboards. This layer also represents the bare schematics of a product. These include the peripherals on the board and their configuration. The names used are merely codes for different board/device configurations.

It also quotes some board names as examples:

> sardine, trout, goldfish

So, given a retail smartphone like a Moto G5 or a Galaxy S8... How to get the board name of it? Also, I tried some google searches like "`smartphone name` + board name" but since the word "board" is to broad I ended up with a tons of unrelated results. I also searched on the Android -> Settings -> about phone and found infos like Kernel version, build number but not what I was looking for.

Comment: Is [this page](https://elinux.org/Android_Device#Product_Files) any use? This seems [to be the location for them](https://android.googlesource.com/device/) - the pattern is **manufacturer** / **PRODUCT_DEVICE** (ie board name).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out `Build.BOARD`. Documentation: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html#BOARD

Comment: @EJoshuaS I'm confused. OP asked how to get the board name, and I provided the answer. Why should that be a comment?